# Implication implies another implication

Tags: logic, proof-writing

We know that, for example, $\forall abcd\left( a\sim{b}\wedge c\sim{b}\Rightarrow a\oplus c\sim{b}\oplus d \right)$. How to formally prove that this statement implies $\forall {a}'{b}'{c}'{d}'\left( {a}'\sim{b}'\wedge {c}'\sim{d}'\Rightarrow {a}'\oplus {c}'\sim{b}'\oplus {d}'\wedge {c}'\oplus {a}'\sim{d}'\oplus {b}' \right)$? Although pretty obvious, I'm struggling to prove it.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what are you asking... What does it mean $\sim$ ? And ⊕ ? Is it [Exclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) ? And the variables ? are they sentential variables ?

Comment: If so, ⊕ is commutative (see truth table). Thus $a′⊕c′ \sim c′⊕a′$

Comment: Let's assume we have an arbitrary magma $\left( M,\oplus  \right)$ consisting of a set $M\ne \varnothing $ and an arbitrary binary operation $\oplus $. The binary relation $\sim{}$ defined on the set $M$ is also an arbitrary one. We know that $\forall abcd\in M\left( a\sim{}b\wedge c\sim{}d\Rightarrow a\oplus c\sim{}b\oplus d \right)$. How to formally prove that this implication implies the following implication $\forall efgh\in M\left( e\sim{}f\wedge g\sim{}h\Rightarrow e\oplus g\sim{}f\oplus h\wedge g\oplus e\sim{}h\oplus f \right)$?

Comment: Naturally, if any two $a\sim{}b$ and $c\sim{}d$ imply that $a\oplus c\sim{}b\oplus d$, we could simply swap $a\sim{}b$ with $c\sim{}d$ and $c\sim{}d$ with $a\sim{}b$, resulting in $c\oplus a\sim{}d\oplus b$ but my goal is to write it down using more formal notation. I'm struggling with the rules of inference.

Comment: It is enough to prove that ⊕ is commutative.

Comment: As far as I understand, in the general case it is possible that $\exists xy\in M\left( x\oplus y\ne y\oplus x \right)$.